# Искажение конца строк JS при загрузке по FTP

Tags: ftp, javascript

Загружаю `JS` файл (кодировка `windows-1251`) на `ftp` через `filezilla`. После загрузки - смотрю файл на сервере или скачиваю обратно. В нём искаженный формат конца строк, т.е. вместо того, чтобы код на несколько строк размещать - всё "собралось" в кучу.

Подскажите, есть идеи из-за чего такое может возникать?

--Ошибка оказалась из-за того, что почему-то формат переноса строк стоял `MAC`. Выставил в `Notepad++` Правка-Формат конца строк-`Win`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [обсуждение на одном форуме](http://phpclub.ru/talk/threads/ftp-%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0.67164/) на тему глюков аплоада по ftp, правда в ней обсуждется ситуация, когда добавляются лишние строки, но, думаю, идея одна)